# Sort Array of object by object field in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I am getting an array of "product"s from a resolver getting data from a json endpoint.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.products = this._route.snapshot.data.products;
  console.log('products: ', this.products);
}
```

where one of the objects in this array is in the format

```
 {
    "id": 3645,
    "date": "2018-07-05T13:13:37",
    "date_gmt": "2018-07-05T13:13:37",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": ""
    },
    "modified": "2018-07-05T13:13:37",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-07-05T13:13:37",
    "slug": "vpwin",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "matrix",
    "link": "",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "VPWIN"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "",
        "protected": false
    },
    "featured_media": 0,
    "parent": 0,
    "template": "",
    "better_featured_image": null,
    "acf": {
        "domain": "SMB",
        "ds_rating": "3",
        "dt_rating": ""
    },
    ...
},
```

What I want to do is sort this array by the field `title.rendered`

In olden times, in AngularJS, I would simply use an `orderBy` pipe in the template set to this field.  Apparently, this is removed in Angular and from doing research it seems the preferred method is to sort the data itself, such as in `ngOnInit`.

But I can't figure out how to sort `products` by `producs.title.rendered`.

Comment: You can see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript/50600956#50600956

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can simply use `Arrays.sort()`

```
array.sort((a,b) => a.title.rendered.localeCompare(b.title.rendered));
```

Working Example :

```js
var array = [{"id":3645,"date":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","date_gmt":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","guid":{"rendered":""},"modified":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","modified_gmt":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","slug":"vpwin","status":"publish","type":"matrix","link":"","title":{"rendered":"VPWIN"},"content":{"rendered":"","protected":false},"featured_media":0,"parent":0,"template":"","better_featured_image":null,"acf":{"domain":"SMB","ds_rating":"3","dt_rating":""},},{"id":3645,"date":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","date_gmt":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","guid":{"rendered":""},"modified":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","modified_gmt":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","slug":"vpwin","status":"publish","type":"matrix","link":"","title":{"rendered":"adfPWIN"},"content":{"rendered":"","protected":false},"featured_media":0,"parent":0,"template":"","better_featured_image":null,"acf":{"domain":"SMB","ds_rating":"3","dt_rating":""}},{"id":3645,"date":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","date_gmt":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","guid":{"rendered":""},"modified":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","modified_gmt":"2018-07-05T13:13:37","slug":"vpwin","status":"publish","type":"matrix","link":"","title":{"rendered":"bbfPWIN"},"content":{"rendered":"","protected":false},"featured_media":0,"parent":0,"template":"","better_featured_image":null,"acf":{"domain":"SMB","ds_rating":"3","dt_rating":""}}];
array.sort((a,b) => a.title.rendered.localeCompare(b.title.rendered));
 
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: What's the `localeCompare` about, and why is it different to Luis' answer? I've never seen it.

Comment: @Steve From Mdn -The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order. It is preferable to use localeCompare when you are sorting string values.

Answer (score 24):

**Try this**

```
products.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.title.rendered - b.title.rendered;
});
```

**OR**

You can import lodash/underscore library, it has many build functions available for manipulating, filtering, sorting the array and all.

Using underscore: (below one is just an example)

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
let sortedArray = _.sortBy(array, 'title');
```

Answer (score 5):

Not tested but should work

```
 products.sort((a,b)=>a.title.rendered > b.title.rendered)
```

Comment: Yup.  Thanks, I was really confused about the compare a,b when reading about it on MDN.

Comment: While this will often work, it is not a consistent compare function - it is not symmetric.

Comment: @ASDFGerte can you elaborate?  What's the better way?

Comment: @Steve Did you look at the (currently five times upvoted) duplicate suggestion's top answer? Note that, as many suggested already, `localeCompare` exists already, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This will not work: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785)